# Keycloak invalid_token Didn't find publicKey for specified kid

Tags: load-balancing, access-token, keycloak, keycloak-services, wildfly-12

I am using keycloak to secure my rest service and I am able to get the token , but when I am using this token for to get my rest service response, getting following error:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private
X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: WildFly/11
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Wed, 30 Jan 2019 07:42:45 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="demorealm", error="invalid_token", error_description="Didn't find publicKey for specified kid"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 71
<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>Unauthorized</body></html>
```

I followed below links but didn't get any output to solve this problem.

[keycloak bearer token error - Didn't find publicKey for specified kid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45246609/keycloak-bearer-token-error-didnt-find-publickey-for-specified-kid)

[Didn't find publicKey for kid ,Keycloak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44457100/didnt-find-publickey-for-kid-keycloak/54437079#54437079)

**Edit 1 -**

As per the detail token is properly generating with following command

```
curl -X POST -k -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -i 'https://<IP-ADDRESS>/auth/realms/apirealm/protocol/openid-connect/token' --data 'username=cwlcadmin&password=password@123&client_id=api-client-id&grant_type=password&client_secret=a682049d-587c-4c38-a594-814f08b0ca76'a@123&client_id=api-client-id
```

But when using this token hitting to rest-api,above declare exception is coming

```
curl -X GET -k -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJpeVlweXZtQU9Sc2RtNXlibWNqWUVSRUxJTnVFR2RNOThDeFVMSmdUTHFvIn0.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.mPVPVdoRpwXU5Im9E8tlLz3DMrM8NrJ-oRiRZL0hceaszU0H58ca2HKhrtncY2WzCxidcuPPxb1fIh3XNR7C-Q-ifOS4VaIbAbH3pAehmhuBqu0gq3LAfVw8vBWVClVP1iKtPOz4cGeKqGQpKRRO1f8epSihVnRe3NWk1WVaD63jexc0EqawZpY-DqH1VDf5xpz8BY4UUqAAfAq0X6kZ7kBoqoiHFofS5eZJHx1mbN-N6qiCwGSwXP-V6JucoBygmqVDkoNCS9Ebx9DyQlXHStSd_KGbCLeIgMlYVPB8vsUy55IcrZGNJWVFsWcvudqTXwW2Tg8BBq-tsFkVuABs5w' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -i 'https://<IP-ADDRESS>/api/v2/0/zones'
```

FYI - Using Wildfly and Load-balancer also which is provided by Wildfly

Comment: Is your keycloak running in server or your local machine ? Where you are running web services local machine or same server where you installed keycloak? Which version of keycloak

Comment: Hi Subodh , my keycloak and wildfly all are  running on remote server and in front I have wildfly load balancer and rest call is handled  by wildlfy via keycloak authentication.

Comment: How did you get your access token, is it for demorealm

Comment: @ravthiru : yes for demorealm.

Comment: you need to check you client names are same in you application and keycloak

Comment: Yeah Ravthiru , I checked both having same name. It is saying invalid token may I know what are the possible reason for token invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last after couple of days struggle we are able to resolve the issue and issue with the Subsystem added in Wildfly server ,it should be like this

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.1">
            <secure-deployment name="sure-admin-web.war">
                <realm>Realm_Name</realm>
                <resource>CLIENT_APP</resource>
                <use-resource-role-mappings>true</use-resource-role-mappings>
                <auth-server-url>https://<KEYCLOAK-IP>:8666/auth/</auth-server-url>
                <ssl-required>NONE</ssl-required>
                <credential name="secret">7df18c0d-d4c7-47b1-b959-af972684dab0</credential>
            </secure-deployment>
        </subsystem>
```

in our case we missed  `<ssl-required>NONE</ssl-required>` and in `<auth-server-url>` we added wrong load-balancer url while it should be Keycloak URL.

FYI - Load-Balancer in working on `HTTPS` while keycloak running on `http`

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. My back end app was in spring boot.
Turns out application.properties needed keycloak.realm-key to be set.

Refer to

```
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/master/securing_apps/topics/oidc/java/java-adapter-config.adoc
```